# Unable to connect with local server via android device

Tags: android, xampp, localhost, server

installed XAMPP server, created database and successfully accessed it from chrome browser as well as from android emulator. However whenever i try to run application from my Samsung device, its refusing to connect my IP address.

My IP address is not registered in DNS.

I tried:
1) accessing from url- 127.0.0.1 and localhost
2) modified httpd.conf and httpd-xampp.conf file- changed to Require all granted permission
3) uninstalled my Antivirus
4) changed firewall and proxy setting
5) Created new Inbound Rule in firewall advance security
6) re typed INTERNET permission
7) wrote httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json"); in code

Still Im getting following error:

```
  W/IInputConnectionWrapper(22232): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
  W/IInputConnectionWrapper(22232): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
  W/IInputConnectionWrapper(22232): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
  W/IInputConnectionWrapper(22232): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
  D/request!(22232): starting
  W/System.err(22232): org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to
  http://192.XXX.X.XXX refused
  W/System.err(22232):  at   org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:183)
W/System.err(22232):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
W/System.err(22232):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
W/System.err(22232):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
W/System.err(22232):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
W/System.err(22232):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
W/System.err(22232):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
W/System.err(22232):    at com.example.mysqltest.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:111)
W/System.err(22232):    at com.example.mysqltest.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:121)
W/System.err(22232):    at com.example.mysqltest.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
W/System.err(22232):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
W/System.err(22232):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
W/System.err(22232):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
W/System.err(22232):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
W/System.err(22232):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
W/System.err(22232):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
W/System.err(22232):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
W/System.err(22232): Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.0.114 (port 80): connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
W/System.err(22232):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:114)
W/System.err(22232):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
W/System.err(22232):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:460)
W/System.err(22232):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:832)
W/System.err(22232):    at `enter code here`org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
W/System.err(22232):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
W/System.err(22232):    ... 16 more
W/System.err(22232): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: connect failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
W/System.err(22232):    at libcore.io.Posix.connect(Native Method)
W/System.err(22232):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:85)
W/System.err(22232):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
W/System.err(22232):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
W/System.err(22232):    ... 21 more
E/Buffer Error(22232): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
E/JSON Parser(22232): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
W/dalvikvm(22232): threadid=12: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41180438)
E/AndroidRuntime(22232): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
E/AndroidRuntime(22232): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
E/AndroidRuntime(22232):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
E/AndroidRuntime(22232):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
E/AndroidRuntime(22232):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
E/AndroidRuntime(22232):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
E/AndroidRuntime(22232):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
E/AndroidRuntime(22232):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
E/AndroidRuntime(22232):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
E/AndroidRuntime(22232):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
E/AndroidRuntime(22232):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
E/AndroidRuntime(22232): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(22232):    at com.example.mysqltest.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:125)
E/AndroidRuntime(22232):    at com.example.mysqltest.Login$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login.java:1)
E/AndroidRuntime(22232):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
E/AndroidRuntime(22232):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
E/AndroidRuntime(22232):    ... 5 more
I/Choreographer(22232): Skipped 1143 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
E/WindowManager(22232): Activity com.example.mysqltest.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41bea8a8 that was originally added here
E/WindowManager(22232): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.mysqltest.Login has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@41bea8a8 that was originally added here
E/WindowManager(22232):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:419)
E/WindowManager(22232):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:322)
E/WindowManager(22232):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:234)
E/WindowManager(22232):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:153)
E/WindowManager(22232):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:557)
E/WindowManager(22232):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
E/WindowManager(22232):     at com.example.mysqltest.Login$AttemptLogin.onPreExecute(Login.java:103)
E/WindowManager(22232):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
E/WindowManager(22232):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
E/WindowManager(22232):     at com.example.mysqltest.Login.onClick(Login.java:77)
E/WindowManager(22232):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4191)
E/WindowManager(22232):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17229)
E/WindowManager(22232):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
E/WindowManager(22232):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
E/WindowManager(22232):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
E/WindowManager(22232):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
E/WindowManager(22232):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/WindowManager(22232):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
E/WindowManager(22232):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
E/WindowManager(22232):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
E/WindowManager(22232):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to check your local IP address of your PC. Connect the phone to the same network (WIFI). Then use the following address/port to connect to your PC.

In Android:

URL: `your_pc_local_ip`

PORT: `80` (but I think it is not mandatory)

I use in this way and it is working properly for me.

Comment: Thank you Blehi. Its worked! However, my app is working via same network (WIFI) How can I access it with another network?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know that. Sorry.

Comment: Blehi, one more problem.. Now its saying "java.net.SocketException: The operation timed out
 at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connectStreamWithTimeoutSocketImpl" what to do?

Comment: I don't know what can be the problem exactly and unfortunately my laptop died so I cannot tell you exactly how I build the connection. I remember that I tried with both apache and volley and it worked properly. When it gets repared I will update my answer. I hope it will not be too late.

Comment: Np. It got fixed. Actually my IP address got changed due to change in network. Thank you for your response Blehi. :)